# Can C++11 features and library be used in an Objective-C program?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++11

I'm a C++ programmer and I wanna know if I can use C++11 features and standard library (you know, lambdas, functional.h, algorithm.h, auto, range-based for...) in an Objective-C program (that runs on iOS or OS X) . And what is Objective-C++ exactly? Does it have full support to the C++11 standard.

Comment: Yes it is. You can write C++ and Objective-C code in same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**,

Source files should be `.mm` and they'll be compiled as Objective-C++ and not Objective-C. In Objective-C++ files I could use C++ standard library.